# Constructing Chern vs. C-F Chern classes

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, homology-cohomology, vector-bundles, characteristic-classes

In *Characteristic Classes* p. 157, Milnor and Stasheff construct the Chern classes. Let $\xi:E \to B$ be a complex vector bundle of dimension $n$. We proceed inductively:

1. The top  Chern class $c_n$ is defined to be the Euler class of the underlying real bundle; i.e., $c_n := e(\xi_{\mathbb{R}})$.
2. One forms a new bundle $\xi_0$ over $E_0 := E$ minus zero vectors (of fibers), which we define fiber-wise: let $F$ be the fiber (considered embedded in $E$) of $\xi$ and $v \in F$, then $\xi_0^{-1}(v) := F/\mathbb{C}v$. This is a complex bundle of dimension $n-1$.
3. In particular, $\xi_0$ is a real vector $2(n-1)$-bundle, hence we have the exact Gysin sequence
   $$\dots \rightarrow H^{i-2n+2}(B) \rightarrow H^{i}(B) \rightarrow H^{i}(E_0) \rightarrow H^{i-2n+3}(B) \rightarrow \dots$$
   The first map is multiplication by the Euler class, and the second is induced by  $\pi_0 := $ the restriction of $\xi$ to $E_0$.
4. For $i$ small compared to $n$, $H^{i-2n+2}(B) = H^{i-2n+3}(B) = 0$ so $\pi_0$ induces an isomorphism.
5. Now we define $c_{n-1} := \pi_0^{* \,-1}(c_n)$. This is well-defined by (4).

> Can I construct Conner-Floyd classes this way? If not, why not?

I am doubtful: an orientation is needed for the Gysin sequence. In the above case, I think $\xi_0$ got its orientation in a "canonical" way from $\xi$. Is this still the case when we consider other cohomology theories? (Maybe the right answer to this question is that I should be less ignorant of orientations.)

> I ask this question because the references I find all cite "Grothendieck's method." I like this approach--it emphasizes that one only needs the Euler class, which itself facilitates the Thom isomorphism, thus revealing the 'closeness' of the Thom isomorphism and Chern classes. This construction from Milnor-Stasheff similarly makes it very clear that one 'only needs' the Euler class.

I highlight that last bit to invite corrections to my thinking, extra commentary, ...

Comment: Actually I think what I should have said is “$\xi_0$ is canonically oriented since it is a complex vector bundle.”

Comment: A very close approach: [Proposition 2.1](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Conner-Floyd+Chern+class). The question is what axioms your cohomology theory needs to satisfy in order to be able to compute the cohomology of $BU(n)$. Complex oriented and multiplicative seems to be enough.